# Problema con el SCOPE de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tengo un problema con el scope de python, al definir una variable global no la puedo incrementar localmente.

```
>>> count = 10
>>> def contador():
        print count
        count += 1
>>> contador()
```

El siguiente error aparece en la consola.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

Alguien sabe porque sucede? Y como puedo aumentar esa variable global ?

Comment: Creo que tienes que poner `global count` dentro de la función para poder usar una variable global, lo he visto aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855493/referenced-before-assignment-error-in-python

Comment: No me funciona declarandola como global y no es una pregunta repetida es un caso concreto.

Comment: No te funciona esto? https://repl.it/KEeV/0

Comment: El error puede estar en que intentas acceder a la variable count antes de declararla global,  intenta poner global count antes del print, y luego de llamar a la función imprime nuevamente la variable count

Comment: Resuelto, muchas gracias chicos.